# order records based on count of associated records posted by distinct users in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models. User, Language, Link. A link belongs to a user and a language. I want to create a list of top five most active languages on the home page. So I want to pull out five languages in the descending order of the number of distinct users who have posted links under that language.

For instance. Spanish has 6 links all posted by 3 distinct users. Moroccon has 7 links posted by 2 distinct users. French has 5 links posted by 5 distinct users.

So the order of the languages must be French, Spanish, Moroccon.

Here's the models for each object:-

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :links

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :links

class Link < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language
```

I'm a beginner in rails but I have tried out a bit to see how it can be done.

For instance, I tried `Link.select(:user_id).distinct.count` which results in the count of unique users who have posted links. But I don't know how to order the *languages* based on the count of distinct users who have posted links under that language. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of `Rails` do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand language has many users through links. Thus, you can add a has_many association to `Language`

```
class Language
  has_many :users, through: :links
end
```

And then left join `users` table on `languages` and order it by the number of users.

Since `Rails 5` has `left_joins` method, it can be performed just by this:

```
Language.left_joins(:users).group(:id).order("count(users.id) DESC").limit(5)
```

If you don't want to display languages without links, `left_joins` can be substituted by `joins`.

Comment: I was wondering about the has many through association, wasn't sure how to use it. This helped clarify. Thank you!